# Making day 28 the last possible day for a month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to change all my dates with days 29, 30 or 31 to 28.

I saw examples of the use of `EOMONTH()`and that is not what I need, I need only to change these specific dates and I cant find any reference.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And explain what you mean by "change"?  Does this mean updating the actual table?

Comment: @bankybanks do you want to do this in Excel maybe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned [`eomonth()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function I will assume that you are using SQL Server, in which case you can do what you want with [`datefromparts()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
update tablename
set date = datefromparts(year(date), month(date), 28)
where day(date) > 28
```

or if you want a select statement:

```
select 
  case 
    when day(date) <= 28 then date
    else datefromparts(year(date), month(date), 28)
  end as date
from tablename
```

Comment: Could you explain me exactly what this is doing? Also, im using SQL Server Management Studio. I cant update the tables but only modify the queries.

Comment: The expression `datefromparts(year(date), month(date), 28)` returns a date which keeps the year and month of a date but with day = 28 in case the day is later than 28. I edited with a select statement.